# Change react-icon color when hover not working properly

Tags: reactjs, react-icons

I'm trying to change my react icon's color while hover on it. Its only partilly working right now. If mouse is over blank part of the icon then its not changing color. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks

```
<FaGithub
    className='contactIcon'
    color='#515357'
    size={42}
    onMouseOver={({ target }) =>
        (target.style.color = '#e91f63')
    }
    onMouseOut={({ target }) =>
       (target.style.color = '#515357')
    }
/>

[working part][1]


[not working][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAl14.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLeG0.png
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use plain css file with `:hover` and assign `className`, or use `styled-components`

```
// style.css
.contactIcon {
  color: #515357;
}

.contactIcon:hover {
  color: #e91f63;
}

// App.js
<FaGithub className="contactIcon" size={42} />
```

```
const StyledFaGithub = styled(FaGithub)`
  color: #515357;
  &:hover {
    color: #e91f63;
  }
`;

<StyledFaGithub size={42} />
```

Demo

[image: Edit reverent-tdd-k8jufy]